# ESP32 Serial read

Tags: c++, web, esp32

I am trying to have my esp32 serial read from an Arduino Uno and then send that to a website that it's hosting, but it won't print the correct number.
This is the Uno's code.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println("67");
}
```

This is the code for the esp32.

```
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <WiFiServer.h>

WiFiServer server(80);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin("Hi");
  while(WiFi.status() !=WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  server.begin();
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if(!client){
    return;
  }
  value = Serial.read();
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  client.println("Refresh: 5");
  client.println("");
  client.println(Serial.read());
}
```

Comment: You are printing a line but reading a single character.

Comment: Uno is printing "67\r\n67\t\n67\r\n ... very fast. esp32 reads only if a client connects and then reads only one character and sends its ASCII code. ASCII code of '6' is 54. `client.write(Serial.read());` would send 6

Comment: @Juraj it also prints out numbers like 10 and 13 though. Also, is there any way for me to change it to read the entire line?

Comment: ASCII codes for 6, 7, \r and \n. you can use `String line = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this is code for ESP32, it uses readString() instead of read();

```
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <WiFiServer.h>

WiFiServer server(80);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin("Hi");
  while(WiFi.status() !=WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  server.begin();
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if(!client){
    return;
  }
  //value = Serial.read();
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  client.println("Refresh: 5");
  client.println("");
  client.println(Serial.readString()); // or Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
}
```